# ffmpeg scale sampling algorithm

Tags: ffmpeg

What sampling algorithm does ffmpeg use for scaling by default?

Here I found all the options: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-scaler.html#scaler_005foptions, but not sure what algorithm is used?

Answer (score 4):

Default scaler is `bicubic`.

See https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/869401c/libswscale/utils.c#L1229